# Dagger generated code compilation failed when using @Singleton annotation

Tags: dependency-injection, singleton, dagger-2, dagger

I am using `Dagger - 2.6` and i have the following classes.

```
public class Trigger {

    public static JSONObject triggerLambda(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        DataTransformerComponent daggerDataTransformerComponent =  DaggerDataTransformerComponent.create();
        return daggerDataTransformerComponent.getHandler().handle(jsonObject);

    }

}
```

Data Handler class:

```
public class DataHandler {


    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DataHandler.class.getName());


    private A a;


    @Inject
    public DataHandler(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public JSONObject handle(JSONObject input) {
        LOGGER.info("Json input received - " + input.toString());
        return a.executeTransformation(input);
    }

}
```

And a dependency:

```
public class A {

    @Inject
    public A() {
    }

    public JSONObject executeTransformation(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        System.out.println("a");
        return null;
    }
}
```

My component class looks like:

```
@Component
public interface DataTransformerComponent {

    DataHandler getHandler();
}
```

When i compile the above code it runs absolutely fine.

Now i want to make my A dependency @Singleton. 
So i change my dependency class and component class as follows:

```
@Singleton
@Component
public interface DataTransformerComponent {

    DataHandler getHandler();
}
```

Dependency class:

```
@Singleton
public class A {

    @Inject
    public A() {
    }

    public JSONObject executeTransformation(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        System.out.println("a");
        return null;
    }
}
```

But now the generated component shows compilation errors saying:

`A_Factory` not found and it fails in the initialize() method.

DaggerDataTransformerComponent :

```
@Generated(
  value = "dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor",
  comments = "https://google.github.io/dagger"
)
public final class DaggerDataTransformerComponent implements DataTransformerComponent {
  private Provider<A> aProvider;

  private Provider<DataHandler> dataHandlerProvider;

  private DaggerDataTransformerComponent(Builder builder) {
    assert builder != null;
    initialize(builder);
  }

  public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
  }

  public static DataTransformerComponent create() {
    return builder().build();
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private void initialize(final Builder builder) {

    this.aProvider = DoubleCheck.provider(A_Factory.create());

    this.dataHandlerProvider = DataHandler_Factory.create(aProvider);
  }

  @Override
  public DataHandler getHandler() {
    return dataHandlerProvider.get();
  }

  public static final class Builder {
    private Builder() {}

    public DataTransformerComponent build() {
      return new DaggerDataTransformerComponent(this);
    }
  }
}
```

I am unable to figure out why it does not create _factory class when i use @Singleton annotation.?.

Comment: Can you post the exact error messages?

Answer (score -4):

Just use regular JavaScript + node.js, its a lot simpler